# Flutter: how to access variable in initState() and Constructor outside?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, asp.net-web-api

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create variable url to call parameter to  put in _newbloc, i cannot initialize url to widget.id without put in initstate and i cannot put _newbloc in constructor  because it cannot be access in initstate. this is my code

```
class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget{
   static final theKey = GlobalKey<_DetailsScreen>();
   final  Rows model;
   
   DetailsScreen({ Key? key, required this.model }) : super(key: theKey);

  @override
  _DetailsScreen createState() => _DetailsScreen();
}

class _DetailsScreen extends State<DetailsScreen>{
  _DetailsScreen(){
    final detailBloc _newsBloc = detailBloc(utl: url); // cannot be access outside
  }
  final detailBloc _newsBloc = detailBloc(utl: url);
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    _newsBloc.add(GetDetailList());
    String? url = widget.model.id; //cannot be access outside
    
    super.initState();
  }
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `late` keyword to `_newsBloc`, then you can initialize it in `initState()`

```
class _DetailsScreen extends State<DetailsScreen>{

  late final detailBloc _newsBloc;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    String? url = widget.model.id; //cannot be access outside
    _newsBloc = detailBloc(utl: url);
    _newsBloc.add(GetDetailList());
    
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Hehe :) You were faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget{
   static final theKey = GlobalKey<_DetailsScreen>();
   final  Rows model;

   DetailsScreen({ Key? key, required this.model }) : super(key: theKey);

   @override
   _DetailsScreen createState() => _DetailsScreen();
}

class _DetailsScreen extends State<DetailsScreen> {

   late detailBloc _newsBloc;

   @override
   void initState() {
      _newsBloc = detailBloc(utl: widget.model.id);
      _newsBloc.add(GetDetailList());
      super.initState(); 
   }
   /// Remaining code
}
```

Initialize the bloc in the `initState`, and add the `late` keyword to _newsBloc property. You dont really need the `url` variable.